# Split an html string in 2 parts: before and after <img> tag

Tags: java

I have some html string which can have an  tag, like this:

```
<p> blablabla <img> an image</img> again blablabla</p>
```

I want to remove the image tag, **and get the part before and after in a string array.**

**edit:**
After calling

```
String[] splitted = htmlStr.split("regex");
```

Result would be:

```
splitted[0] = "<p> blablabla ";
splitted[1] = "again blablabla</p>"
```

I'd say a regex is required, mind that img tag can be different from string to string: it can have one or more attributes for example.

Comment: [Use an HTML parser if your img tag will be arbitrary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/451590)

Comment: I just have to clear the img part, for this reason I'd avoid using a whole html parser. @Roman: because String.split method requires a regex

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `HTML Parser` for parsing `HTMLs`, because your tags may vary, which can't be handled completely by `Regex`.

But, given for this case that you just want to remove the `<img>` tag, regardless of the attributes it has, you can use the below regex: -

```
String str = "<p> blablabla <img> an image</img> again <img href = sadf> " + 
             "asdf asdf </img>blablabla</p>";

str = str.replaceAll("<img\\s*[^>]*?>[^<]*?</img>", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
<p> blablabla  again blablabla</p>
```

**You would like to see the below link: -**

- [Why shouldn't you parse HTML with Regexp](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)
- [The true power of Regular Expression](http://nikic.github.com/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html) - Do go through it.

You can rather use HTML parsers like: -

- [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [HTML Cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer, String.split() or an HTML parser for complex HTMLs with many IMG tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
String str = "<p> blablabla <img> an image</img> again blablabla</p>";
int start = str.indexOf("<img");
int end = str.indexOf("</img>");
String imgTagValue = str.substring(0,start) + str.substring(end, str.length());
```

However, if in a single line more than `<img>` tags are used, it should be parsed appropriately.

Refer [here](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It works if after the "int end.." line I make substrings using the indexes start and end, but I think that just a String.split with a good regex would be more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all html-tags you can use this code:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```